# Как можно создать дополнительную OC в скрытом режиме?

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Т.е к примеру сижу, смотрю фильм (делаю свои дела), а на другой OC 
(а может не OC, расскажите о альтернативе) в это время трудится кликер.

Двигается мышь, нажимаются кнопки на клавиатуре, и тд. При этом, я абсолютно ничего не вижу.

Нет никаких идей для реализации, прошу, если можете, расскажите в каком направлении двигаться, яп не важен (любой).

**Это вообще возможно?**

P.S Не совсем знаю, какие метки ставить.

Comment: Это ? [тыц](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) [тыц](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/)

Comment: Придётся проверять автокликером (что всё работает в фоне). Про первую прогу слышал, думаю не сработает, про вторую пока мало знаю.

Comment: VmVare, Virtualbox. Только кликер - ещё ладно, а вот майнер - бессмысленно ставить, слишком мало ресурсов на виртуалку уйдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй развернуть машину (ту где  поддерживается твоя игра) с помощью Hyper-V (он очень лёгкий в настройке) и с помощью test complete (тоже очень прост) эмулировать нажатие на игру